# Possible future uses of Bose-Einstein condensates?

Tags: technology, physics, quantum

Using future technology what possible uses are there for matter in the form of Bose-Einstein condensates? I have heard possibilities of using it for communication and even weaponizing it, using the matter as a projectile but I am unsure of what is really possible and what else it could be used for.

What are the possible future uses within the laws of physics of being able to control matter as a Bose-Einstein condensate?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this question? Are you world building in a context where Bose-Einstein condensates have a significant role? Or do you just need a MacGuffin / handwavium and Bose-Einstein sounded like a good name?

Comment: Current widely used possibility is superconducting magnets. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @fgysinreinstateMonica it has to be within the laws of physics, im not after any hand wave ideas, Im trying to find out what their uses can be in a near hard-science space opera.

Comment: @ksbes thats a good use but im sure there could be many other uses?

Comment: I heard BEC could be used for super-sensitive measurements, like spotting underground gas deposits or oil fields, or to build extremely precise gyroscopes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is essentially a "list type" question.  These are generally off topic as there is no practical way to choose a "best" answer.

Comment: @StephenG I could narrow the scope if necessary, I didn't want to split it into repeated questions for different uses, like weaponry, communication, sensing etc but could if needed.

Comment: The other problem here is that a BEC is really just a mathematical model of any type of particles (or quasi-particle) with specific properties.  What you are asking is not much different from asking for ways to use the Ideal Gas Equation or something like that.  You cannot directly relate such a model to e.g.weapons or communications - any future technology could involve an important component that requires modelling as a BEC.

Comment: @StephenG Its the coherent pattern the matter can take with all atoms at the same energy levels that I am wondering about how it can translate when we are able to control it with greater precision, it seems it can have great benefits over other states of matter?

Comment: I'm not (personally) seeing a way to make that a suitable question for WB SE.  Of course I'm just one member, so maybe others have suggestions (or just plain disagree with me :-) ).

Comment: @StephenG Thats fair, I appreciate your input and ill prepare a more defined question if this question is deemed to broad.

Comment: You're asking us to speculate on the use of particles we don't actually know anything about and can't manipulate for testing purposes. We can look back into history and see the same problem with radio waves and electricity - until people could work with science on a practical level, there really wasn't a way to develop a foundation for that speculation. Consequently, any answer is just a guess, which is off topic for all of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @JBH I don't think it is a guess, they can slow light in a Bose-Einstein cloud in a way where no information is lost, this gives possible advancements in communication and this one aspect could effect many areas of science and technology.

Comment: @RandySavage can you direct me to a paper or article discussing that?

Comment: @JBH this video mentions slowing the light https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIc5llW66sU  , I will try to find the other articles I read or watched.